# How to create calculator with bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc, sh

How to create calculator with bash ?

example

```
    read -p "calculator count: "  calc
    echo '$((calc))' | bc
```

i input

```
2+2
```

output

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
```

how to fix ?

I just want to make text input in the script, so for the addition of + , - , x - and / . I input manually

for example I want `2+2+1*3/2`

After I enter, the result will appear

Comment: Get rid of the single quotes since it makes it literal.  Use double quotes or none for `echo '$((calc))'`.  So it should be `echo "$((calc))"` or `echo $((calc))`

Comment: thank you, work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already pointed out by Terrance, you need double quotes; otherwise, the `$` sign is sent literally.

Also, remove the double parentheses which ask Bash to do the calculation. In which case you wouldn't need to pipe to `bc`, but Bash only does integer arithmetic.

So it should be either

```
echo "$((calc))" # evaluated by Bash
```

or

```
echo "$calc" | bc
```